# How can i get files specific files names from directory?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(countriesMainPath + "\\" + currentDownloadCountry, "*.jpg");
```

But not only gif i want to specify that also it will be only files that contains the name infrared. For example i have files name 0infrared.gif and also 0visible.gif and i want to get all the files that are infrared.

Comment: Your comments say that you want `.gif` files, but your code says `.jpg`. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string partialName = "infrared";
 DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");
 FileInfo[] filesInDir = dir.GetFiles("*" + partialName + "*.*");
 foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
 {
    string fullName = foundFile.FullName;
    Console.WriteLine(fullName);
 }
```

Comment: This is going to get _all_ files with "infrared" in them, not just `.jpg`s or `.gif`s.

Comment: thats what op wants

Comment: "not only gif i want to specify that ***also*** it will be only files that contains..."

Answer (score 1):

This will get you all files with infrared in file name and with extension jpg

```
string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(countriesMainPath + "\\" + currentDownloadCountry, 
             "*infrared*.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(
    countriesMainPath + "\\" + currentDownloadCountry, 
    "*infrared*.*");
```

This will return all the files contain infrared in their file name.

Comment: Welcome to SO! read [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to get to know how to use code block

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you look for. ref: [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0c31115-f6f0-4de5-a62d-d766a855d4d1/directorygetfiles-with-searchpattern-to-get-all-dll-and-exe-files-in-one-call?forum=netfxbcl)

```
public static string[] GetFiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
{
    string[] searchPatterns = searchPattern.Split('|');
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    foreach (string sp in searchPatterns)
        files.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, sp, searchOption));
    files.Sort();
    return files.ToArray();
}
```

Usage

```
var wantedImgs = GetFiles(
    dirYouWant, "*infrared*.jpg|*infrared*.gif", 
    earchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe `*infrared*.(jpg|gif)` will work

Comment: The `Directory.GetFiles` method doesn't support pipe characters as a way to alternate between two options.